# MongoDB index with specific field value

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Good day!

I have a collection with documents like

```
{
  account_id: "accountOne"
  state: stateOne
}
```

I want to make sure that there is only one document that has pair ***accountID<->state***, where state equals to ***stateOne***, but I want to be able to have many documents where state equals to any value different from ***stateOne***

For example I want to be able to have this data in my collection:

```
{
  account_id: "accountOne"
  state: stateOne
}

{
  account_id: "accountOne"
  state: stateTwo
}

{
  account_id: "accountOne"
  state: stateTwo
}
```

If I make **uniq** index like {account_id: 1, state: 1} I will get an error.
Is there any way to do it via db ? Or I have to do it via my sevice logic?

Comment: Maybe provide us the command how you created the index. And the most important question: What do you mean by "I will get an error"? Please provide the error you get!

Comment: If I make uniq index  on {account_id: 1, state: 1}  fields I could not create several documents with "state: stateTwo" - I will get duplicate key index error on insert

Comment: What is the criteria that distinguishes stateOne from other states (other than that there can be only one stateOne that is associated with an account_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   { account_id: 1, state: 1 },
   { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { state: stateOne } }
)
```